# Change FK placement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `table1`

```
id  | some_field
----------------
1   | text1
2   | text2
3   | text3
```

And `table2`

```
id  | table1_id | some_field
----------------------------
1   | 3         | lorem ipsum
2   | 1         | lorem ipsum
3   | 2         | lorem ipsum
```

There are `one to one` relations between `table1.id` and `table2.table1_id` fields.

I need to change FK placement to `table1` (means create `table2_id` in `table1` and fill it with related keys form `table2`) to get structure like this:

```
id  | table2_id | some_field
---------------------------
1   | 2         | text1
2   | 3         | text2
3   | 1         | text3
```

And then drop `table1_id` field (but it's not related to the question).

The question is can I make it with like one common SQL statement that will update all rows with saving of current relationships?

Comment: Update a table and drop a column apparently can not be done with a single statement.

Comment: Are the `table2_id` values meant to be in some way related to the current `id` and `table1_id` values in table 2? Because I cannot see that in your current sample. Also, may sound obvious, but are we guaranteed that there's *at most* one row in table 2 for any particular table 1 row? If not, how should that be handled?

Comment: @Serg, I now and I'm asking for `update` statement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes, they must be related. I've fixed the description. And there is one to one relationships.

Comment: as I understand, do you need add column `table2_id` to `table1`  and then UPDATE that column with appropriate values from `table2`. is this correct ?

Comment: And what exactly is your problem now? You don't know how to write an update statement? Or you don't know how to join? Where's your effort? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @OtoShavadze, yes.

Comment: @fancyPants, I don't have a clue how to make statement that will update `table2_id` column without using concrete values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) can update rows from one or more `JOIN`-ed tables.

Assuming you have already created the column `table2_id` in `table1`, your `UPDATE` query should be like this:

```
UPDATE table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
SET table1.table2_id = table2.id
```

That's all. It should report as modified the same number of rows there are in `table1` (or in `table2`, they should have the same number of rows).

Answer (score 2):

This is done with a simple join.

```
alter table t1 add column table2_id int;

update t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
set t1.table2_id = t2.id;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c39a2d/1/0)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I've maked @axiac answer because he was first.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right

```
UPDATE table2  
JOIN table1 ON (table2.table1_id = table1.ID)
SET table2.ID = table2.table1_id
  , table2.table2_id = table2.ID 
  , table2.some_field = table1.some_field;
```